# How can I webscrape a Website for the Winners

Tags: python, web-scraping

Hi I am trying to scrape this website with Python 3 and noticed that in the source code it does not give a clear indication of how I would scrape the names of the winners in these primary elections. Can you show me how to scrape a list of all the winners in every MD primary election with this website?

https://elections2018.news.baltimoresun.com/results/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parsing is a little bit complicated, because the results are in many subpages. This scripts collects them and prints result (all data is stored in variable `data`):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://elections2018.news.baltimoresun.com/results/"
r = requests.get(url)

data = {}
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
for race in soup.select('div[id^=race]'):
    r = requests.get(f"https://elections2018.news.baltimoresun.com/results/contests/{race['id'].split('-')[1]}.html")
    s = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    l = []
    data[(s.find('h3').text, s.find('div', {'class': 'party-header'}).text)] = l

    for candidate, votes, percent in zip(s.select('td.candidate'), s.select('td.votes'), s.select('td.percent')):
        l.append((candidate.text, votes.text, percent.text))

print('Winners:')
for (race, party), v in data.items():
    print(race, party, v[0])

# print(data)
```

Outputs:

```
Winners:
Governor / Lt. Governor Democrat ('Ben Jealous and Susan Turnbull', '227,764', '39.6%')
U.S. Senator Republican ('Tony Campbell', '50,915', '29.2%')
U.S. Senator Democrat ('Ben Cardin', '468,909', '80.4%')
State's Attorney Democrat ('Marilyn J. Mosby', '39,519', '49.4%')
County Executive Democrat ('John "Johnny O" Olszewski, Jr.', '27,270', '32.9%')
County Executive Republican ('Al Redmer, Jr.', '17,772', '55.7%')
```

Comment: Thank you, this does help a lot, however, my question was more to do with get the results from every single election. The page contains many different local elections beyond county executive. So, my question is how you would do this by referencing all the other pages that list the results for all the other elections?

Comment: @DataScienceAcolyte The page https://elections2018.news.baltimoresun.com/results/ has only results from "Governor / Lt. Governor" to "County Executive", which are included in the answer. What else do you mean?

Comment: There are drop down menus that include other offices. Such as democratic central committee. I am looking to get all those offices.

Comment: @DataScienceAcolyte So it's easy, look for all `<option>` values on that page  (there are URLs for  contests) and use the snippet I provided to scrape the urls (maybe it will require little modifications).